# Wann wird "nach" als Postposition verwendet?

Tags: difference, preposition

Es ist mir aufgefallen, dass ***"nach"*** manchmal als Präposition und manchmal als Postposition  verwendet wird, wenn die Bedeutung "gemäß" oder "laut" ist.

> meiner Meinung nach
>
> nach Adam Riese

Gibt es einen Unterschied? Wann benutzt man welche Variante?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt in der Sprache keine feste Grenze dafür. Schon das erste angeführte Beispiel wird auch als

> nach meiner Meinung ...

durchaus häufig genutzt und [ist in der Bedeutung gleichwertig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nach_zu_hin_entsprechend#Bedeutung6a).

> Adam Riese nach ...

hingegen ist nicht gängig. Einerseits ist *"nach Adam Riese"* eine etablierte Redewendung, die nach Umstellungen eben nicht mehr stimmt, andererseits ist das in seinen möglichen Bedeutungen vielvältige *"nach"* in der nachgestellten Position deutlich anfälliger für Mehrdeutigkeiten der Art

> So habe ich Adam Riese nach Hause begleitet

Weil man diese in der Sprache der besseren Verständlichkeit wegen zu vermeiden sucht, würde man das "nach" dort durch das im Kontext am nächsten Stehende und mit gleichem Kasus kommende "zufolge" ersetzen:

> Adam Riese zufolge ...

Man beachte, dass [auch *"zufolge"* vorgestellt sein kann](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zufolge), nur ist es in dieser Variante in der Alltagssprache in Deutschland kaum bis gar nicht anzutreffen.